# How to check TLS version used with Http requests in PROD?

Tags: ssl

We received notification from external service providers regarding they enforcing `TLS 1.2` in PROD from some date. I am pretty sure that from our client systems, `http` calls to those services must be using `TLS 1.2` But I wanted to confirm to avoid any risk and issues last minute. I cannot install tools like `wireshark` or anything else in `PROD` for obvious reasons.

Is anyone aware of checking this given above constraints ? Thanks !!

Comment: You basically ask if you can check the TLS version from an __unknown__ environment with an __unknown__ client and without the ability to install anything anywhere. These are too much unknowns.

Comment: What *can* you install? What OS do you use? What built-in tools do you have? Can you get this metadata from the firewall? Can you get a report from the external service provider?

Answer (score 4):

You can absolutely use Wireshark to monitor the traffic. Just don't install it directly on the server, but instead use a Network Tap.

This is a device that copies all network traffic going through the device, while being fully transparent.